# Java code error with finding the average of the entries in an array

Tags: arrays

Can anyone help me solve this problem, it's for my Intro to Java class! When given an array of integers, I need to determine the average. My code currently prints out 3 when it should be printing 3.5:

```java
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] counts = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int sum = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    while (counter < counts.length) {
        sum = sum + counts[counter];
      counter++;
    }

    System.out.println(sum / counts.length);

  }
}
```

Can anyone help me fix the bug in my code? Thank you!

Comment: sum should be double or float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java does integer division, which is the same as regular real division but you get rid of the remainder. In this situation, after summing the entries of the array to 21, when it divides the number by 6 it yields 3 because when dividing it gets 3 remainder 3. To solve for this issue, simply define sum as a double in the beginning rather than as an int.